# ElasticSearch Max Agg on lowest value inside a list property of the document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking to do a Max aggregation on a value of the property under my document, the property is a list of complex object (key and value).  Here's my data:

```
[{
    "id" : "1",
    "listItems" : 
        [
            {
                "key" : "li1",
                "value" : 100
            },
            {
                "key" : "li2",
                "value" : 5000
            }
        ]
},
{
    "id" : "2",
    "listItems" : 
        [
            {
                "key" : "li3",
                "value" : 200
            },
            {
                "key" : "li2",
                "value" : 2000
            }
        ]
}]
```

When I do the Nested Max Aggregation on "listItems.value", I'm expecting the max value returned to be 200 (and not 5000), reason being I want the logic to first figure the MIN value under listItems for each document, then doing the Max Aggregation on that.  Is it possible to do something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: Yes your solution worked for what I needed, flagged as answer, thank you for your help.

Comment: While we're on this topic, how would you suggest I apply this similar logic to a search query?  So say I want to do a numeric range query on a listItem.value of 150.  Applying the same concept, I want the matches to happen on the MIN value from each list against that 150, so in this case, only the 2nd record got returned

Comment: Sorry @user989953, could not reply to your other question, as it was late here in India. I have added my answer to your other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64073549/10348758, please go through this and let me know if this resolved your issue ?

Comment: I am quite curious to know whether this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64073549/10348758 worked for you or not. It would be great if you could reply there, and tell me if your issue is resolved or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search query performs the following aggregation :

1. [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `id` field
2. [Min aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html) on `listItems.value`
3. [Max bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-max-bucket-aggregation.html) that is a sibling pipeline aggregation which identifies the bucket(s) with the maximum value of a specified metric in a sibling aggregation and outputs both the value and the key(s) of the bucket(s).

Please refer to [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html), to get a detailed explanation on it.

Adding a working example with index data, index mapping, search query, and search result.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "listItems": {
        "type": "nested" 
      },
      "id":{
        "type":"text",
        "fielddata":"true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "listItems" : 
        [
            {
                "key" : "li1",
                "value" : 100
            },
            {
                "key" : "li2",
                "value" : 5000
            }
        ]
}
{
    "id" : "2",
    "listItems" : 
        [
            {
                "key" : "li3",
                "value" : 200
            },
            {
                "key" : "li2",
                "value" : 2000
            }
        ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "id_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "nested_entries": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "listItems"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "min_position": {
                            "min": {
                                "field": "listItems.value"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "maxValue": {
            "max_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "id_terms>nested_entries>min_position"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "id_terms": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "nested_entries": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "min_position": {
              "value": 100.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "nested_entries": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "min_position": {
              "value": 200.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "maxValue": {
      "value": 200.0,
      "keys": [
        "2"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial post was mentioning nested aggregation, thus i was sure question is about nested documents. Since i've come to solution before seeing another answer, i'm keeping the whole thing for history, but actually it differs only in adding nested aggregation.

---

The whole process can be explained like that:

- Bucket each document into single bucket.
- Use nested aggregation to be able to aggregate on nested documents.
- Use `min` aggregation to find minimum value within all document nested documents, and by that, for document itself.
- Finally, use another aggregation to calculate maximum value among results of previous aggregation.

Given this setup:

```json
// PUT /index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "children": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "value": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
// POST /index/_doc
{
  "children": [
    { "value": 12 },
    { "value": 45 }
  ]
}
```

```json
// POST /index/_doc
{
  "children": [
    { "value": 7 },
    { "value": 35 }
  ]
}
```

I can use those aggregations in request to get required value:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "document": {
      "terms": {"field": "_id"},

      "aggs": {
        "children": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "children"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "minimum": {
              "min": {
                "field": "children.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "result": {
      "max_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "document>children>minimum"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "aggregations": {
    "document": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "O4QxyHQBK5VO9CW5xJGl",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "children": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "minimum": {
              "value": 7.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "OoQxyHQBK5VO9CW5kpEc",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "children": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "minimum": {
              "value": 12.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "result": {
      "value": 12.0,
      "keys": [
        "OoQxyHQBK5VO9CW5kpEc"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There also should be a workaround using [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html#_script_7) for calculating max - all that you will need to do is just find and return smallest value in document in such script.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you, would love to see some sample code to get started.  What would my terms aggregation be done on?